# Jetpack compose: Add drawable to start of TextField

Tags: android, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

In the code shown below, I have a TextField that accepts user input. How do I add a drawable to the start or end of the TextField? I can't find any attribute for setting *drawableStart* or *drawableEnd*.

```
var text by rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf("") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(1f)
        .padding(30.dp),
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    placeholder = { Text(text = "Email") },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email)
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [drawableStart equivalent in TextField of Jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67182717/drawablestart-equivalent-in-textfield-of-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `leadingIcon` and `trailingIcon` attribute in the [TextField documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#TextField(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material.TextFieldColors)). Use **leadingIcon** in place of *drawableStart* and **trailingIcon** in place of *drawableEnd*. Find below a sample implementation:

```
var text by rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf("") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(1f)
        .padding(30.dp),
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    placeholder = { Text(text = "Email") },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email),
    leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = "Localized description") },
    trailingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Info, contentDescription = "Localized description") }
)
```